# How can I know if a given XULElement has the focus or not

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm using a firefox addon Keysnail.
Keysnail adds a prompt (`xul:textbox`) on the bottom, and I want to know if the focus is on this prompt or not.

Did a research and found a way using `document.activeElement`, but its not working.
`document.activeElement` is returning `HTMLInputObject` when the focus is on the prompt while getting the textbox by `document.getElementByID` returns a `XULElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.activeElement` is the correct way to get the focused element. The reason why it returns an unexpected value for you - each `xul:textbox` tag has an anonymous (meaning: not visible to usual DOM methods) `html:input` tag as its child and the keyboard input is actually being handled by this `html:input` tag. `document.getElementById("textbox-id").inputField` will give you this HTML input field. Or you can go the other way round: `document.getBindingParent(document.activeElement)` should give you the `xul:textbox` element.

Documentation: [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement), [document.getBindingParent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL/XBL_1.0_Reference/DOM_Interfaces#getBindingParent)